# Why html file must go before js file when addFiles in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm creating a meteor package, very simple one like [this](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commit/sidebar9-5-1)

```
  api.addFiles(['errors.js', 'errors_list.html', 'errors_list.js'], 'client');
```

I noticed that if I change above code to

```
  api.addFiles(['errors.js', 'errors_list.js', 'errors_list.html'], 'client');
```

Meteor says: `Template is not defined`.

It is very hard to find out what caused this error. And why js file cannot go before html file in addFiles?

Comment: Does your `errors_list.js` file contain helpers and callbacks for the `errors_list` template defined in `errors_list.html`? If so, I can answer your question.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess & say you don't have `templating` in your dependencies, eg `api.use(['templating'],'client');`

Try adding it & then order shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Kyll, yes,there are helpers in errors_list.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Spacebars (the default templating engine), templates are defined in HTML files :

```
<template name="fooTemplate">
  ...
</template>
```

You can then access this template from everywhere else, be it HTML or JS:

```
<!-- HTML file -->
{{> fooTemplate}}

//JS file
Template.fooTemplate
```

If you try to do such an access before the template has been created, it will fail.
Meteor packages load files sequentially. This is how you control the load order.

If you try to use a template before it has been defined, it's `undefined` and will throw an exception when you try to access it (something along the lines of `fooTemplate is undefined`).

Thus, as in everything in programming, always **initialize** first and **use** later.
Put your HTML files before the JS, and you're good to go.